# create a button element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a button element with these features but i seem stuck and i dont know why. Here is the question
Create a BUTTON element with ID of filter-query, and give it a CSS class of mdc-icon-button and material-icons. Set its text to filter_list.

This is what i did

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" 
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

<title>Mini App</title>
<button id = "filter-query" class ="mdc-icon-button material-icons"> 
filter_list
        </button>

<style>
  body{
    background-color: white;
  }
```

but its not running. could anyone please help me out

Comment: Why is the button in the `<head>` and not `<body>`? What exactly do you mean by not running? Do you mean display? Or is is meant to do something? If so , what?

Comment: @JonP Samuel is obviously taking an online quiz or an interactive tutorial. The engine is probably not detecting the answer as correct. Maybe because of the remarks you mentioned. The spaces between the attributes = sign might be an issue as well.

Comment: i tried placing it in the body also but nothin... yes i mean the button created is not displaying

Comment: Well it definitely belongs within the `<body>` tags. Please provide a more complete example with the `<button>` in the body which demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the shortest answer to the question as posed is:

`<button id='filter-query' class='mdc-icon-button material-icons'>filter_list</button>`

Naturally, another valid answer is javascript:

```
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.id = 'filter-query';
btn.classList.add('mdc-icon-button');
btn.classList.add('material-icons');
btn.textContent = "filter_list";
```

Answer (score 0):

@Boycott Dev and others, you guys are correct but it seems you guys are forgetting the other part of the question which state : "and give it a CSS class of mdc-icon-button and material-icons"

i think you should add a css style

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a specific answer backed with references. If you have a suggestion or need clarification leave a comment. We have guidelines on [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The code you shared was incomplete and out of order. I completed and ordered it, but I dont know if this is exactly what youre trying to do. Please add more detail.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" 
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

<title>Mini App</title>
    <style>
      body{
        background-color: white;
      }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    
    </body>
    <button id = "filter-query" class ="mdc-icon-button material-icons"> 
    filter_list
            </button>

    
</html>
```